# I am getting an error while trying to include reader.php

Tags: php, syntax, fatal-error

I keep getting this error even when I have put reader.php in the same directory.

require_once(): Failed opening required 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Reader/OLERead.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/spywgc/reader.php on line 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the reader.php file to see of if the path to the OLERead.php file is hard coded to a specific path. If so, modify the path to reflect where you placed the OLERead.php file.